# How to check the user's permissions in views.py?

Tags: python, django

In my views.py file on my Django site, I have a class based view that needs to alter a variable based on the user's permissions.

So if a user has the `pro_view` permission, then it sees one thing. Otherwise if it has `basic_view` then it sees another.

How can I access this inside my `get_context_data(self, **kwargs):` function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`has_perm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm):

So, from inside your `get_context_data` you can do something like this:

```
if self.request.user.has_perm('applications.admin_access'):
    # do this
else:
    # do that
```