# Django Staff Member Required Decorator does Infinite Loop if access denied

Tags: python, django

I am using the Django staff_member_required decorator to protect an admin area of the site.

I am using it like this

```
@staff_member_required(login_url=reverse_lazy('account_login'))
def kommando_home(request):
    # business logic
    return render(request, 'kommando/home.html', context)
```

I am using the custom login so users do not see the Django login page if they hit the URL.

However, if a user who does not have staff permision logs in, it just results in this:
[image]

I can add a redirect parameter to the decorator but that always redirects the user to the url provided even if the user has permission.

I tried looking into customizing the decorator but I do not see any way to check if permission denied is raised.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the infinite loop is this.  The @staff_member_required requirement is not met since the user is not staff, which takes the user to the login_url, but the user is already logged in, so the account_login takes the user to it's `next` parameter, which is the original page with staff_member_required, etc...

What you might try instead is to check for the permission in the view itself, then redirect from there:

Check out Serafeim's answer at [How to check the user's permissions in views.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24478067/how-to-check-the-users-permissions-in-views-py)

> Use has_perm:
>
> So, from inside your get_context_data you can do something like this:

```py
if self.request.user.has_perm('applications.admin_access'):
    # redirect to one page
else:
    # redirect to the other page
```